# Rewrite Rule to include redirecting for an existing directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the .htaccess script:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

which will redirect all requests into the `index.php` script, except for existing files or directories that exist. However, I have the directory `/lib` which contains the libraries for the webapp, and I would like to extend the rewrite rule to redirect requests to `/lib[/(.*)]` (the directory and everything under it) into `index.php` as well, but so far, I have been having issues.

What lines do I need to add to my `.htaccess` file to add support for that rule?

p.s.

The webapp that I am doing this for currently exists on a test server, and is all stored under a higher base, so the lib URL at the moment is `http://localhost:8080/c2/lib`. I have not defined the `/c2` part in the `.htaccess` as I am trying to keep it disparate, and only have the webapp do the processing.

I am aware that I could just move the `/lib` directory into a higher directory, but I am trying to do this with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional rule, which rewrites all requests for `/lib/*`

```
RewriteRule ^lib/.*$ index.php [L]
```